# change wxhaskell layout programmatically

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

I want to switch layouts after an event (ie click on button). So I set the new layout and repaint the panel, but the layout doesn't change. (It does so only after I resize the frame by hand.) What's the magic sauce that's missing? Thank's for helping me out!

```
import Graphics.UI.WX

buildGUI = do
  f <- frame [ text := "Hello" ]

  controls <- panel f []
  ctext <- staticText controls [ text := "Foo" ]
  butn <- button controls [text := "change layout"]
  set controls [ layout := row 0 [margin 5 (widget ctext),
                                  margin 5 (widget butn) ]]

  set f [ layout := widget controls ]

  set butn [on command := do
      -- switch layout, button first, text second
      set controls [layout := row 0 [ margin 5 (widget butn)
                                    , margin 5 (widget ctext) ]]
  {-
     repaint doesn't do it, but if I resize the frame by hand,
     the layout changes
  -}    
      repaint controls         ]

  return ()

main = start buildGUI
```

Comment: I don't know wxWidgets, but the command you're looking for is typically called "pack" or "repack"...

Comment: Thanks, I found a function called `refit` which does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself after googeling with MathematicalOrchid's comment in mind. The function is called `refit`.